# Run tensorflow on linux by python3 pip

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have installed python and tensorflow on my linux, This is my all step that I done:

```
sudo apt install python3 python3.pip
sudo pip3 install ––upgrade pip
pip3 install ––upgrade setuptools
pip3 install tensorflow
pip3 install keras
```

This version of tensorflow and keras is installed:

```
Alt@mx:/mnt/Project/ML/AE
$ pip3 show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.4.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/Alt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: keras-preprocessing, wrapt, gast, tensorboard, six, google-pasta, h5py, typing-extensions, tensorflow-estimator, astunparse, wheel, opt-einsum, grpcio, protobuf, flatbuffers, termcolor, absl-py, numpy
Required-by:
```

And:

```
Alt@mx:/mnt/Project/ML/AE
$ pip3 show keras
Name: Keras
Version: 2.4.3
Summary: Deep Learning for humans
Home-page: https://github.com/keras-team/keras
Author: Francois Chollet
Author-email: francois.chollet@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/Alt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: pyyaml, h5py, scipy, numpy
Required-by: 
Alt@mx:/mnt/Project/ML/AE
```

I create a simple code on vscode :

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant("Hello, TensorFlow!")
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

But when I run it by vscode I got :

```
Alt@mx:/mnt/Project/ML/AE
$ /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/Project/ML/AE/simple_auto_encoder.py
Illegal instruction
Alt@mx:/mnt/Project/ML/AE
```

What is my mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may refer to the instruction set that the binary supports. Check the compatibility with your CPU.
For more information check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45866).

I would also like to mention that you don't have to install separately the `keras` library because it is included in `tensorflow`.

Comment: I can run tensorflow by anaconda but I want to use without anaconda @NewLow

Comment: That's because anaconda probably uses an earlier version that the latest that you get from pip. Try to install an earlier version and see if problem is fixed. Check this also. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45744